# SXA Redirect URL with Query String

Tags: sxa, redirect

I've tested a number of redirect scenarios using the map URL in SXA, but cannot get the URL structured below to redirect. Is it possible to redirect a query string with the following format? It seems the equal sign cause issues since Sitecore saves the redirect with an equal sign in the database.

`/directory/details.aspx?idone=1&idtwo=152&Idthree=4&idfour=0&truefalse=False&New=True&word=`

Comment: Tried, but no luck...
^/directory/details.aspx?idone\=1\&idtwo\=152\&Idthree\=4\&idfour\=0\&truefalse\=False\&New\=True\&word\=(.*)$

Comment: Tried, but no luck...^/directory/details.aspx?idone.1.idtwo.152.Idthree.4.idfour.0.truefalse.False.New.True.word.(.*)$

Comment: Tried, but no luck...^/directory/details.aspx?idone(.)1(.)idtwo(.)152(.)Idthree(.)4(.)idfour(.)0(.)truefalse(.)False(.)New(.)True(.)word(.)(.*)$

Comment: Tried, but no luck...^/directory/details.aspx?idone(.*)1(.*)idtwo(.*)152(.*)Idthree(.*)4(.*)idfour(.*)0(.*)truefalse(.*)False(.*)New(.*)True(.*)word(.*)(.*)$